# How do you start a MySQL server on linux?

Tags: mysql, linux, command-line

Pretty simple question here. I just want a SQL database on my version of Kali linux so I can practice SQL.

I opened the command line and entered tried to start mysql and get an error.

```
> mysql -u root
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'
```

I also made sure it was already installed using apt-get.

What are the steps I need to take to be able to make a database with tables and data that I can query?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't know about Kali, but on Ubuntu it would be

```
$ sudo service mysql start
```

Once that command returns, the `mysqld` service has started, so you can use the `mysql` client to connect to it.

Of course, you also have to make sure you have the `mysql-server` package installed, not just `mysql-client` and `mysql-common`, and that you've initialized the database instance. Complete post-installation instructions can be found in [the official documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/postinstallation.html), but the short version is

1. Make sure the installer has created the `mysql` user account. This is the account that will "own" the server process once it starts.
2. Change to your data directory. (I used the installer's default of `/var/lib/mysql`; you can change this by editing `my.cnf`.)
3. As root, execute the server daemon with the `--initialize` switch. Check `whereis` to determine the correct path, then

   ```
   $ sudo /path/to/mysqld --initialize --user=mysql
   ```
4. This command will twiddle itself for a while, then display an automatically-generated password and exit. Once the command returns, the database instance has been initialized and the system tables created. You can now start the database instance normally (using `service start`), then log in as the ***database*** user **`root`** (which is *not* the same as the ***system*** user **`root`**) using the password from above, then change your password, create a new database user, log in as *that* user, create a user database, and start creating tables.

Again, [the official documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/installing.html) is the place to look for this; if any of the instructions in [the official documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/installing.html) differ from my instructions, you should ignore me and follow [the official documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/installing.html)'s instructions.

Comment: Boom! that's what I needed. Would you mind adding how you would initialize the db so I could do run a CREATE TABLE command?

Answer (score 2):

If `sudo service mysql start` doesn't work for you, please try running `mysqld_safe` and don't kill the process. Use another tab to check the status of mysql service. This should solve your `mysqld.sock` issue.

If it doesn't work out, then please edit your my.cnf file and add the following:

```
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
```

And the permissions,

```
sudo chmod -R 755 /var/lib/mysql/
```

Hopefully, this should do it.

Comment: Thanks that didn't make a difference for me but it's still useful knowledge to have.

Answer (score 1):

On my version of kali (2022-rolling), even though it's installed as MySQL, it's run as mariadb. To start it is:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/mariadb start
```